# Kivy MapView offline

Tags: android-mapview, kivy, offline

I'm planning to write a Kivy app containing a (small) offline map. Kivy's Mapview widget seems to be a good choice to display maps but before I start diving into it further one question that I couldn't figure out: Is it possible to use Mapview offline, by using locally stored tiles?

Comment: Have you tried doing it?

Comment: Well, no. I was wondering if anyone knows whether it is worthwhile to try. If noone knows, I'll try...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do it, it turns out it is not that complicated to do but it took some research (at least for a beginner like me). Here is a rough outline:
1. MapView supports mbtiles as source as detailed in the documentation - mbtiles can be created in TileMill
2. I wanted a map in Openstreetmap style, so I downloaded openstreetmap-carto from github. The installation manual explains quite well what needs to be done in order to obtain a map in this style
4. There the biggest challenge was to set up and manipulate a PostGIS database. This link helped: http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=loading_osm_postgis
There were some additional issues along the way but all could be solved by combing through the internet.

Comment: Do you may have a tutorial about this?

Comment: I haven't worked on this in three years, so I'm afraid all I can offer is the above description.